# how can save images larger than 1MB on sqlite database android?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to build a notebook app using the SQLite database. everything works ok but whenever the images larger than 1MB Is added to the row of the database there won't be any new row shown on the recyclerView. while i delete all the items of the database it will work again correctly.

the question is how can i save images larger than 1MB in my database?

**this is the main database:**

```
public class MainDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MainDatabase.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

/// memo library
private static final String TABLE_NAME_MEMO = "memo_library";
private static final String MEMO_ID = "memo_id";
private static final String MEMO_TITLE = "memo_title";
private static final String MEMO_MEMO = "memo_memo";
private static final String MEMO_DATE = "memo_date";
private static final String MEMO_IMAGE = "memo_image";
private static final String MEMO_LOCATION = "memo_location";

/// tasks library

public MainDatabase(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    try {
        String memo_query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_MEMO +
                " (" + MEMO_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                MEMO_TITLE + " VARCHAR, " +
                MEMO_MEMO + " TEXT, " +
                MEMO_DATE + " VARCHAR, " +
                MEMO_IMAGE + " BLOB NOT NULL, " +
                MEMO_LOCATION + " VARCHAR);";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(memo_query);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**this is the method to insert the data:**

// add data method:

```
void addMemo(MemoData memoData) {
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(MEMO_TITLE, memoData.getTitle());
        contentValues.put(MEMO_MEMO, memoData.getMemo());
        contentValues.put(MEMO_DATE, memoData.getDate());
        contentValues.put(MEMO_IMAGE, convertImage(memoData));
        contentValues.put(MEMO_LOCATION, memoData.getLocation());

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME_MEMO, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Memo Exception:  " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**this is the part of the code that i wrote to add the image through its path:**

```
 private byte[] convertImage(MemoData memoData) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = null;

    if (memoData.getImage() != null){ // memoData is a class which i put the path of the image as String object in it
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(memoData.getImage());

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.header1);
    }


    stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    assert bitmap != null;
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

    //assert stream != null;
    return stream.toByteArray();
   //return new byte[0];
}
```

Comment: SQLite in Android is not designed for large BLOB columns like that. I strongly recommend hat you store your images as ordinary files, and perhaps store the filenames in the database.

Comment: Consider storing the URI in DB (rather than the actual content), and fetch the actual image only when it needs to be displayed.

Comment: I know this way but in case of deleting the images from the memory the data will be damaged. And the user will loose a part of his data.